# React createRef() does not trigger on Netlify Deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, invisible-recaptcha

I am implementing an invisible google recaptcha using the react-google-recaptcha package. Everything works fine locally, all is trigerred and works smoothly but when deployed on Netlify, when you click the button the flow stops on the recaptchaRef.current.execute().

These are the main parts of the code:

```js
const recaptchaRef = React.createRef();

class App extends Component {
  triggerRecaptcha = () => {
    recaptchaRef.current.execute();
  }
  
  handleChange = () => {
    // verify recaptcha
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ReCAPTCHA
          ref={recaptchaRef}
          sitekey={KEY}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          size="invisible"
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.triggerRecaptcha}>Proceed</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Basically locally the handleChange will be trigerred. On Netlify it is not, and after debugging it seems that the issue on the deployed version is *recaptchaRef.current.execute();*

Any one has any clue what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: It might be a `KEY` issue. Is it valid for Netlify?

Comment: it seems you are right... it wasnt picking it up because i used the full url. Thanks and sorry for the time

Answer (score 1):

This involved Recaptcha admin console not being configured correctly. Sorry for time lost and thanks @UjinT34